# Mapbox tiles are not showing for V3 (401 not authorized) and messed with V4

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm struggling here with Mapbox integration with Leaflet.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        // create a tile layer sourced from mapbox
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapId/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=AccessTokenValue').addTo(map);
```

For this current code I get a messed up map : 
[image]
When I change V4 with V3 I get the 401 header with a message :

```
{"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Can you guys help me through this? 
Today is my frist day using Mapbox & leaflet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply forgot to add the stylesheets.